# Bayesian knowledge tracing using R

Tags: rstudio, hidden-markov-models, bayesian-networks

I've been trying to use R to estimate BKT group parameters. I found the following site, which seems like it might be helpful to do this:

https://www.noisebridge.net/wiki/Machine_Learning/HMM_R_Example

However, I'm having a lot of trouble applying this to all the KC's for my data. Has anyone else done something like this and would like to explain how to go about doing it?

Additionally, if possible, I'd like to find the individualized difference weights after finding the BKT group parameters, but if I could just do the latter right now, I'd be happy.

Comment: What does your data look like?  What have you tried?

Comment: The data is a transaction file in excel with rows being an attempt at an answer by a student. I tried modifying the code in the link to work for my data but there were a lot of errors and I was unsure what the middle portion of the code was actually doing. I think I need to add a for loop somewhere to loop through all the KCs because as far as I can tell, this code only works for one KC, but beyond that I can't tell.

Comment: Hello, is the dataset in this link available somewhere I can reach?